# Conditional validators can't be removed in Angular service

Tags: angular

I wrote a few functions in a shared form service (several components use the same service) that has a couple of sections that need to have required validators if a checkbox is unchecked. The way I wrote it, it works fine to add the validation, but when I check the checkbox, the validation is not removed, and my form will not be valid even if all the other required information is filled in.

Here's the checkbox

```
    <div class="billing-checkbox" *ngIf="multiStepForm.controls['billingContact']">
        <input type="checkbox" id="billingContact" [(ngModel)]="useBillingContact" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="getFormService().billingToggle()" />
        <label for="billingContact">Use as billing contact</label>
    </div>
```

The formGroup I am working with (in the service)

```
multiStepForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    orgInformation: this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address: ['', [Validators.required]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      city: ['', [Validators.required]],
      state: ['', [Validators.required]],
      zip: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactFirstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactMiddleName: [''],
      contactLastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactSuffix: [''],
      contactEmail: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      contactPhone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
      contactExt: [''],
      billingContact: [true],
      billingFirstName: ['', [this.conditionalValidator(() => this.billingRequired, Validators.required, 'billingFirstName')]],
      billingMiddleName: [''],
      billingLastName: ['', [this.conditionalValidator(() => this.billingRequired, Validators.required)]],
      billingSuffix: [''],
      billingEmail: ['', [Validators.email, this.conditionalValidator(() => this.billingRequired, Validators.required)]],
      billingPhone: ['', [Validators.minLength(10), this.conditionalValidator(() => this.billingRequired, Validators.required)]],
      billingExt: [''],
      terms: [false],
    }),
```

And the functions handling validation (also in the service)

```
billingToggle() {
    this.billingRequired = !this.billingRequired;
    this.multiStepForm.get("orgInformation.billingFirstName")!.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.multiStepForm.get("orgInformation.billingLastName")!.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.multiStepForm.get("orgInformation.billingEmail")!.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.multiStepForm.get("orgInformation.billingPhone")!.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.multiStepForm.get("orgInformation.billingExt")!.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  conditionalValidator (predicate: BooleanFn, validator: ValidatorFn, errorNamespace?: string): ValidatorFn {
    return formControl => {
      if (!formControl.parent) {
        return null;
      }
      let error = null;
      if (predicate()) {
        error = validator(formControl);
      }
      if (errorNamespace && error) {
        const customError: any = {};
        customError[errorNamespace] = error;
        error = customError;
      }
      return error;
    };
  }
```

[This is the initial state before unchecking the checkbox. The next button is enabled because the form is valid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ1db.png)

[Once the checkbox is unchecked, the form is invalid because the billing contact fields are now required.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l2Aq.png)

[If I check the checkbox again, it should remove validation for the billing contact fields and the orgInformation formGroup should be valid again, but it is not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTFFG.png)

The form should only require the fields before billingContact if the checkbox is checked. Instead once it's been unchecked once, the fields after billingContact remain required.